# GNU make: Generate automatic dependency and use then for linking objects

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have a lot of files that compile to individual executable.
I know how to use make to do this when the files are standalone, but I have introduced a general class definition that I would like to link with *some* of the programs.
Problem is that if I link the class to all the other programs, every modification of the class file will recompile all of the other files, even when not needed.

### Setup

```
.
|
|  Makefile
|
|__ src
|   |__ program1.cpp
|   |__ program2.cpp
|
|__ include
|   |__ Class.h
|   |__ Class.cpp
|
|__ build
```

Now assume that `program1.cpp` has the line `#include "../include/Class.h"` at the beginning (i.e. it depends on that file) and the call the class, maybe something along the lines of

```
Class a;
a.print();
```

while `program2.cpp` doesn't use nor include the class file.
I want my Makefile to be able to

- Compile respectively `program1(2).cpp` into the executables `build/program1(2)`.
- Detect the difference in dependency on the file `Class.h` so that when I modify the class, only the first program will recompile.

Sort of a minimal working Makefile looks like:

```
SRCDIR := src
DSTDIR := build
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
SRCSOBJ := $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
DST := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(DSTDIR)/%)

INCLDIR := include
INCLSRC := $(wildcard $(INCLDIR)/*.cpp)
INCLOBJ := $(INCLSRC:%.cpp=%.o)

all: $(DST)

$(DSTDIR)/%: $(SRCDIR)/%.o $(INCLOBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $< $(INCLOBJ)

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $<
```

Problem is when I modify the `Class.cpp` file, it recompile every file in the `src` folder.
Not problems when there are only two of them, but I am implementing the solution to [project euler](https://projecteuler.net/), even at about 20 solutions it take a significant amount of time to compile.

I am aware about the flags `-MMD -MP ...` coming from the [auto-dependency tool](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) of GNU compilers and kind of made it work.
It managed to make it recompile only necessary files to objects files, but I wasn't able to use the generated dependencies for the linking stage.
This resulted in bad linking errors that I resolved by linking every `program*.o` to the `Class.o` file, but then back to the starting problem as at every modification of the class every files needed to be recompiled.

If someone could help me with this I would be very thankful :)

**Edit: Minimal Working example**
I replaced `Class.*` with `Name.*` but it doesn't change anything.
The structure of the project is given at the beginning of the post, as is the minimal Makefile.

Name.h

```
#include <string>

class Name
{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Name( const std::string& str);
    void print() const;
};
```

Name.cpp

```
#include "Name.h"
#include <iostream>

Name::Name(const std::string& str):name(str) {}

void Name::print() const
{
    std::cout << name << '\n';
}
```

program1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../include/Name.h"
int main()
{
    Name myname("Leo");
    myname.print();
    return 0;
}
```

program2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "No dependencies\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit n°2: Utilize GNU auto-dependency tool**
By using the same setup, and just modifying the `Makefile` by adding the dependency flags, as follows:

```
SRCDIR := src
DSTDIR := build
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
SRCSOBJ := $(SRCS:%.cpp=%.o)
DST := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.cpp=$(DSTDIR)/%)

INCLDIR := include
INCLSRC := $(wildcard $(INCLDIR)/*.cpp)
INCLOBJ := $(INCLSRC:%.cpp=%.o)

#Dependencies flags
DEPFLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP

all: $(DST)

$(DSTDIR)/%: $(SRCDIR)/%.o $(INCLOBJ)
    g++ -o $@ $< $(INCLOBJ)

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ $(DEPFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Then we get three dependencies files `*.d`.
program1.d

```
src/program1.o: src/program1.cpp src/../include/Name.h
src/../include/Name.h:
```

program2.d

```
src/program2.o: src/program2.cpp
```

Name.d

```
include/Name.o: include/Name.cpp include/Name.h
include/Name.h:
```

If GNU can detect those dependency, then why can't we use them when come the linking.
If we know that `program1.o` depends also on `Name.h` it seemed to me that we could add `Name.o` to the list of object to link when creating the executable `build/program1`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [mre], I don't get it. The compilation stage can be nicely automated with GCC's flags. But the linking cannot, AFAIK. You need to provide the dependencies in the Makefile by yourself.

Comment: The papers on the following site might provide useful information: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/

Comment: @thebusybee I added a minimal example, I also added what I get when using auto-dependencies. If we can detect that some file depends on an other when compiling, then couldn't we use this knowledge so that when creating the executable, we add the corresponding object?

Comment: @Bodo I actually added a link to this webpage in the post. I managed to implement it but it only covers the compilation part, then I could use this to link the resulting object files.

Comment: Your conclusion is not true in any case. -- The dependencies for compiling are really simple and the preprocessor can find them via its directives. -- I can include the header file for "Name" into the source of a module "program2" without the need to link the corresponding module "Name" to it, for example if I'm only interested in some declaration. -- Granted, with deeper insight, an automation can conclude which modules need to be linked. I didn't met such automation in all the years. But if it exists, I'm keen to know.

Comment: @Leo The dependency of an object file from the corresponding source file is trivial. The automatic dependency generation covers header files files to trigger the compilation of a source file that includes the modified header file. This can be automatically done by parsing the source code. As a result, no additional files will be compiled, it only adds a dependency to a rule like "*if `A.h` was modified, compile `B.c` to get `B.o`". It does not add `A.h` to the compile command.

Comment: There is no general rule that an `#include "A.h"` in the source requires to link an object named `A.o` generated from `A.c`. It might as well require `A1.o`, `A2.o`, and maybe `B.o` if some function in `A1.c` calls a function from `B.c`, or it may even not require any additional object file if only types or preprocessor symbols are used from the header file.

Comment: The Arduino IDE seems to have a mechanism to generate dependencies for "library" source files from the include directives. It seems to require that header and corresponding sources are in the same directory in a specific tree. Maybe you can check the source code of the Arduino IDE to see how it's done there.